# Fragment UI turns blank after switching views

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

In a Xamarin.Android app with mvvmcross I'm currently facing a weird glitch:

A fragment I have inside of a tabbed navigation menu turns completely blank after switching fragments and clicking any text box for a few times. And turns visible again when I close the keyboard.

.
[image: blankView][image: CorrectView]

Comment: Looks like it looses it's state somewhere. Did you try to set `Activity` attributes to handle configuration changes with for example Keyboard? Also you could try to enable `RetainInstance = true` on the `Fragment`

Comment: @Martijn00 The fragments do use RetainInstance = true ! I have not set any attributes for the keyboard what would you recommend?

Comment: Maybe something like `ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation`